# jqplot line chart with json array - Chart not loaded

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jsp, jqplot

My Spring Controller class looks like this

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/cityGridView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List showLineChart(Map<String, Object> map,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        List<Object> rows = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<MapTable> list = contactService.fin();
        for (MapTable table : list) {
            List<Object> dataRow = new ArrayList<Object>(1);
            dataRow.add(table.getSRDate());
            dataRow.add(table.getNumberOfSR());
            rows.add(dataRow);
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

In my jsp i handle response like this. (seems issue in here ??)

```
<div id="chart1" style="width: 800px;height: 500px" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
            var ret = null;
            $.ajax({
              async: false,
              url: url,
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(data) {
                ret = data;
              }
            });
            return ret;         
          };

    var jsonurl = 'cityGridView.html';

    var today = new Date(); 

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', jsonurl, {
          title:'Data Point Highlighting',
          dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
          dataRendererOptions: {
              unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
              },
          axes:{
            xaxis:{
                label: "SR_DATES",
                'numberTicks' : 7,
                min: '2012-10-01',
                max: '2012-10-07',
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                rendererOptions:{tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
                tickInterval:'1 day', 
                tickOptions:{
                    formatString:'%Y-%#m-%#d'
                    }
            },
            yaxis:{
                label: "SR COUNT",
                tickOptions:{
                    formatString:'%d'
                    },
                min:10,
                max:30
            }
          },
          highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
          },
          cursor: {
            show: true
          }
      });
    });

    </script>
```

- My JSON like this

  [["2012-10-01",15.0],["2012-10-02",20.0],["2012-10-03",25.0],["2012-10-04",18.0],["2012-10-05",22.0],["2012-10-06",24.0]]

Here shows my MapTable Class

```
public class MapTable {

    private Date SRDate;
    private int numberOfSR;

    public Date getSRDate() {
        return SRDate;
    }

    public void setSRDate(Date sRDate) {
        SRDate = sRDate;
    }

    public int getNumberOfSR() {
        return numberOfSR;
    }

    public void setNumberOfSR(int numberOfSR) {
        this.numberOfSR = numberOfSR;
    }
}
```

contactService.fin(); Method called to Service Classes & finally it in DAO classes.
Data also correctly come like above i mentioned array.here is my DAO class

```
public List<MapTable> fin(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<MapTable> dashboardBeanList = jdbcTemplate
                    .query("select trunc(ASSIGNED_datetime) as SR_DATE, count(*) as COUNT " +
                            "from sbl_service_request_v " +
                            "where SR_TYPE ='Complaint' " +
                            "and DATE_COMMITED  is not null " +
                            "and ASSIGNED_DIVISION  in ('CSO','IT_IVR') " +
                            "and trunc(ASSIGNED_datetime) >= sysdate -30 " +
                            "group by  trunc(ASSIGNED_datetime) " +
                            "order by trunc(ASSIGNED_datetime)",
                                            new Object[] {},
                                new RowMapper() {
                                      public MapTable mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                                                  throws SQLException {
                                          MapTable dashboardBean=new MapTable();
                                          dashboardBean.setSRDate(rs.getDate("SR_DATE"));
                                          dashboardBean.setNumberOfSR(rs.getInt("COUNT"));
                                          return dashboardBean;
                                      }
                                });
        return dashboardBeanList;
    }
```

Comment: I rollback revision 8 because it was made after the accepted answer, and solutions shouldn't be added in a question itself, but instead should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected vs actual JSON data are different in a couple of ways and you have not stated which differences matter. But I'll tackle the `"rows":` bit first as it represents a JSON structural difference (as opposed to data value differences).

Your actual JSON output contains the `"rows":` property because you have returned a `Grid` object from your controller - which had a field called `rows` populated with your list of lists. If you simply want your JSON to contain the list of lists, then return that from your controller: `return rows`.

Your date format is also different, so I would look at the getter method for your `MapTable .getSRDate()` as a first step - there is not enough info/code in your question to address this directly.

Comment: I have changed my above question as per your request & added additional data's to there.
Please check again it and help me to solve that question

Comment: You need to specify the format for the date to your desired format YYYY-MM-DD - the current output is the default toString() representation. You have not addressed the JSON format issues I raised (removing the grid class completely).

Comment: now i removed Grid class & edited the method in controller class.
when i run it, firefox stucked & shows popup message that "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost:8080/Dashboard/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js:16"

& tell me to stop script.any thing goes weong in me JSP code ?

Comment: nickdos : Now my chart x & y axis, background also loaded.thanks
but my data line not shown yet.any issue with my JS script.?

Comment: Use Firefox Firebug or Chrome "inspect element" to look for console errors in your javascript.