# JSON -> serialize object to array (chart point)?

Tags: highcharts, jackson, mybatis

Is there any way (elegant way) to transform from a BDD select:

```
SELECT CONSOLIDATION_DATE d, SUM(CONSOLIDATED_VALUE) v
FROM MON_CONSOLIDATION_FIRST
GROUP BY CONSOLIDATION_DATE
```

into a `JSON` data structure like the following:

```
[[1369265180000, 2], [1369265141000, 3], [1369265141000, 2]]
```

Right now, I got this:

```
[{"D":1369265180000,"V":2},{"D":1369265141000,"V":3},{"D":1369296900000,"V":2}]
```

My "tools": `MyBatis`, `Spring3`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` to http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data

I know I can do it by hand with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000541/jqplot-line-chart-with-json-array-solved), but I'm searching a better way -- considering performance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a (good) solution implementing a ResultHandler with mybatis.

I did this:

```
List<Collection> answer = new ArrayList<Collection>();

@Override
public void handleResult(ResultContext context) {
    final Map<?, ?> consolidations = (Map<?, ?>) context.getResultObject();
    Collection<?> llista = consolidations.values();
    answer.add(lista);
}
```

This is also a good solution for export to csv.